# object passing as undefined in child component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am trying to pass an object as a prop, but I am receiving it as undefined in the child component. If I try the same thing in codesandox works perfect. Any thoughts?

This an example:

***Parent Component***

```
import TestPage from "pages/Test"; 

  const text = {
  crono: "crono",
  watch: "clock",
  start: "start",
  stop: "stop",
  split: "split",
  pause: "pause",
  clear: "clear",
};

export default function Base() {
 
  return (
    <section className="main-container">
      <TestPage text={text} />
    </section>
  );
}
```

***Child Component***

```
export default function Test({ text }) {
  console.log(text);
  return <h1>{text.split}</h1>;
}
```

[here](https://github.com/elisasoto/pt-abril-2021-crono-clock-project-react/blob/feat/routes/src/pages/index.jsx) is the complete project

Comment: Are you sure your error comes from this part of your codebase? It works fine

Comment: Your github project works fine for me, and shows the `split` text. Are you on the correct branch ? And on the root path ?

Comment: I am, thans for testing it though!.